# What do we mean when we say "for all n where n is an element of..."

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

When we write "for all n where n is an element of A, P(n) is true." do we mean for all n, if n is in A then Pn or for all n, n is in A and Pn?

Comment: The first. If $n$ is in $A$, then $\dots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounded quantifiers are $\exists a\in A.P(a)$ and $\forall a\in A.P(a)$ are abbreviations which tell us that we are interested in the elements of $A$ rather than those of the rest of the universe. The expanded versions are: $$\exists a\in A.P(a)\equiv\exists a(a\in A\land P(a))\\ \forall a\in A.P(a)\equiv\forall a(a\in A\rightarrow P(a))$$

Note that the second interpretation that you gave (for all $n$, $n\in A$ and $P(n)$) is not a very good one, because it means that $A$ is equal to the universe of discourse, and that all elements satisfy $P$.

Answer (score 3):

It means the first...symbolically,

$$\forall n\Big(n \in A \rightarrow P(n)\Big)$$  In words, for all $n$, ***if*** $n$ is an element of $A$, ***then*** $P(n)$ is true.

Comment: $~~+1^♥~~$  for you :)