# Quantifiers and their negations

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I was revising logic and I realised that I had a very basic lack of understanding about quantifiers and their negations.

As I understand it ¬$\forall$$x$ $P$($x$) is equivalent to $\exists$$x$ ¬$P$($x$).

So far so simple. But what about quantifiers over a particular set.

Again, as I understand it $\forall$$x$ ($x \in X$) can be thought of as $\forall$$x$ $P$($x$) where $P$($x$) $=$ $x \in X$.

Yet the negation of $\forall$$x$ ($x \in X$) $P$($x$) is $\exists$$x$ ($x \in X$) ¬$P$($x$) rather than $\exists$$x$ ($x \notin X$) $P$($x$).

Are the two equivalent? What am I missing?

Comment: Keywords: bounded quantifiers.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481498/what-do-we-mean-when-we-say-for-all-n-where-n-is-an-element-of/

Comment: Thank you Asaf, the linked question 481498 clarifies it for me. Of course, ($x \in X$) $P$($x$) is not a well formed formula, rather it is an abbreviation for ($x \in X \implies P$($x$)) in the case of the universal quantifier and ($x \in X \wedge P$($x$)) in the case of the existential quantifier. When this is recognised the negations become easily made. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x \in X, P(x)$ is shorthand for $\forall x, (x \in X \implies P(x))$,
 and $\exists x \in X, P(x)$ is shorthand for $\exists x, (x \in X \land P(x))$.

(your " $\forall x (x \in X) P(x)$ " isn't a well-formed formula and doesn't mean anything)

Notice that one uses an implication or the other uses a logical and.

Then the following are equivalent :

$\neg \forall x \in X, P(x) \\
\neg \forall x, (x \in X \implies P(x)) \\
\exists x, \neg (x \in X \implies P(x)) \\
\exists x, (x \in X \land \neg P(x)) \\
\exists x \in X, \neg P(x)
$

So as expected the connectives $\forall x \in X$ and $\exists x \in X$ are still dual to each other.

Comment: Thanks mercio, I see it now, temporary brain fog about what a well formed formula is.

Answer (score 0):

With $X=\{a,b,\cdots z\}$, by De Morgan,

$$\lnot(P(a)\land P(b)\land\cdots P(z))=\lnot P(a)\lor\lnot P(b)\lor\cdots\lnot P(z).$$

Comment: What if $X$ has more than 26 elements? Say, $X$ is the real numbers?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: the question is about understanding the negation of quantifiers and more precisely the role of $x\in X$.

Comment: Yes, and your explanation hinges on $X$ having 26 elements.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: don't be silly, this is irrelevant. By the way, the Italian alphabet does not include the $y$.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that $\exists x\in X\varphi(x)$ is not just a disjunction over $\varphi(x)$ for the elements of $X$, but rather a shorthand for a formula. Once understanding what the shorthand stands for, the negation comes out automatically. So your answer is not particularly helpful in understanding how bounded quantifiers are actually interpreted.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: you didn't read the question.

Comment: Judging by the reply of the OP to the comments I made on the question, I beg to differ. :-)